# Centos 5.7 location of the apache installation

Tags: apache-2.2, centos

I want to know where is the location ($APACHE_ROOT) of the Apache installation in Centos 5.7

```
bash# $APACHE_ROOT/bin/apxs -iac mod_evasive.c
```

Comment: Hmmm....where did you find this specific line of code?

Answer (score 3):

The instructions you read assume that Apache is compiled from the source. If you didn't, just install the `httpd-devel` package:

```
# yum -y install httpd-devel
```

`/usr/sbin/apxs` comes from this package, you can check by running:

```
# yum provides *bin/apxs
```

Comment: ok Thank you i guess with that answer i dont need to know where the apache installation directory  is , apxs is in /usr/sbin

Comment: There is a difference between compiling from source and installing from binary. When you compile from source, all the binaries, libraries, ... go to the `--prefix` path or `/usr/local` by default. But if you install with `yum/rpm`, the binaries are installed to `/usr/(s)bin`, the libraries go to `/usr/lib`, ...

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how you've installed it. Default setting is /usr/local/apache2. If it's not there you can find it with "locate apxs"

Comment: that command display anything about apxs

Comment: I don't understand your comment. If you know where apxs is, you know where APACHE_ROOT is.

Comment: excuse my english when i put locate apxs nothing display

Comment: In this case it is not installed. It's not part part of httpd rpm.

Comment: but apart it is not installed where is Apache installation directory,

Comment: /usr/local/apache2 doesn't exists

Comment: I find out that apxs isn't in apache installation directory. Thank u